# How to include other aspx page to main the main aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I am very new to ASP.NET and I am trying to create a website for learning purposes. I was developing the website in PHP where I used to include another PHP file in the main using `<?php include('static/nav.php'); ?>`. In the same way, I am trying to include another aspx page to the main aspx page for top_nav, side_bar, and footer.  But I am not able to do so. Is there any way to include it ? which I am not able to find it.

I have seen somewhere this code
`#Include virtual="/menu.aspx"` but its not working.

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/partial-view-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: I am not making as per MVC pattern

Comment: you can create a user control and use that control to any page in web forms

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/asp-net-controls-webforms.html

Answer (score -1):

For the main menu bar etc.?
This is normally done without any code or markup on your part.

The concept involves what is called a master form, and then a child form.

So, try creating a new project, and choose ASP.NET frame work).

On the last page, choose web forms - you can un-check https setting

The result is then this:

[image]

Notice the menu bar. That is a bootstrap menu bar.

So, now how do we add a web form, say Hello Word?

When you add a web form, you can choose the "master" form that holds that menu bar etc.

So you go like this:
[image]

You now get this:

[image]

So, our markup is this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
CodeBehind="helloWord.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebWithMenu.helloWord" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Hello Woorld</h2>

</asp:Content>
```

And thus this is the result:

[image]

So you don't' really have to write code - your main "master" page will be part of each new web page you create (as long as you choose new form with master page).

And we can add HelloWord to the menu:

Just open site master, add this:

```
   <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
   --->this        <li><a runat="server" href="~/HelloWord">Hello World</a></li>
```

Now, we get this:

[image]

And if you click on the menu bar, then your HelloWord page will show. So, you can quite much see that we did not have to really write much of anything, and we have that main menu bar that exists for all pages.

this WHOLE process took less time then to write this post!

Now, are there other ways to include content or say another web page?

Well, there is of course iframe - but I think like most, we try and avoid those, but that does let you drop in another page.

There is also what we call "user control"

A User Control is a reusable page or control with an extension of .ascx  and created similar to an .aspx page but the difference is that a User Control does not render on its own, it requires an .aspx page to be rendered.

User Controls are very useful to avoid repetition of code for similar requirements. Suppose I need a calendar control in my application with some custom requirements in multiple pages, then instead of creating the control repetitively you can create it once and use it on multiple pages.

Here is a tutorial:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/creating-user-control-in-Asp-Net/

And you can say start to use say jQuery and REALLY nice is jQuery.ui. jQuery.UI is nice since it will let you load contents of a WHOLE page into the current page, and say pop that up as a dialog.

So there are several choices here. But for a top most menu bar etc., I would adopt the master + child design approach.